# Не сравнивает время

Tags: java, android, время

Есть диапазон времени и если сейчас время входит в этот диапазон - выполнить. Почему-то этот код не работает, но должен. Как исправить?
Ну или же как сделать по другому? (чтобы работало)

```
                    Time time1 = new Time(uFrom * 1000);
                    Time time2 = new Time(uTo * 1000);
                    long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    Time now = new Time(curTime);
                    boolean check1 = now.after(time1);
                    if (check1) Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "1 ok", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    boolean check2 = time2.after(now);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а покажите как вы инициализируете переменные time1 и time2

Comment: оформите код в виде текста, а не картинки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем примере переменная `time2` на самом деле содержит не сегодняшнюю дату, а 1 января 1970

Используйте класс `Calendar` чтобы откинуть от `System.currenTimeMillis()` дату или же чтобы сразу извлечь необходимые поля для времени и перевести в миллисекунды.

UPD: Как верно подмечено, есть библиотека [joda-time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), с ней работа со временем становится приятнее.

Comment: У меня тут только время.

Comment: для уточнений испоьзуйте комментарии. Ответы только для законченого решения проблемы в вопросе

Comment: переменную now вы инициализировали не только временем

Comment: Как исправить?
ps я думал то что он обрезает дату

Comment: я обновил ответ

Comment: Есть очень крутая библиотека JodaTime называется, решает все проблемы. Если есть возможность использовать сторонние библиотеки, я рекомендую присмотреться к ней.